# Why the Switch Statement in Java could contain a FINAL Variable as the CASE?

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, case, final

Why the Switch Statement in Java could contain a FINAL Variable as the CASE? ##

In JDK7 as checked by me a value cannot be reassigned to final variable, as shown below. But, Why the final variable "x" can be included in a Switch Statement for a case  eventhough value for final variable "x" cannot be reassigned?

Why this can be done eventhough Oracle defines that the Java Compiler takes final variable as the value initialized but not the variable name?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4

Please tell me if this is a Technical Error of the Java Compiler or are there Exceptions or Special Use of checking the Case of a Final Variable in a Switch Statement?

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final int x=100;
        //x=200;    //error: cannot assign a value to final variable x

        //The below piece of code compiles
        switch(x){
            case 200: System.out.println("200");
            case 300: System.out.println("300");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what switch does? You might want to read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Why not be able to switch on compile-time constants?

Comment: The `switch` isn't reassigning any values.

Comment: No! @moose please understand me, i know what switch statement does, but, i want to know what is the use of checking different cases of a final variable because it compiles, is this a technical error of the java compiler or are there any exceptions to check a case of a final varible in any Control Statement?

Comment: Imagine the equivalent in if-else .. does it assign any values ?

Comment: @user2060289: So you want to know why the compiler doesn't / can't completely remove the switch-statement? Do you think it could probably optimize your code and remove it?

Comment: @user2060289, so you mean you want to know why doesn't compiler give warning as "unreachable case".. something like that? Am I right?

Comment: I think what the OP is asking is why the compiler won't notice that this code is redundant due to the nature of the final variable x.

Comment: user1428716 The above issue applies to all the control statements.
@moose i doubt that why it won't give an compiler error,
Pradeep Simha yes, something like that, but any way compiler must know that final variables cannot contain different values to implement cases
gekkostate yes, something like that, but any way compiler must know that final variables cannot contain different values to implement cases

Comment: In order for this to be a compiler error the JLS would have to contain a prohibition on using a final variable in a switch statement. Can you find any such restriction?

Comment: @user2060289 so your question is basically "why Java warns about `if (2==3){`? but not about `switch(3){ case 2:`"?

Comment: no i cannot find that restriction @PatriciaShanahan , but oracle has made the java compiler in such a way they minimize technical errors (of the compiler), but as the my code compiles with a final variable in a case statement without any meaning' i want to know if there are exceptions in using final variables in control statements (switch) OR is it really an TECHNICAL ERROR of the JAVA COMPILER,

Comment: @Pshemo no, plz refer my ealier comment,

Comment: @user2060289 Dead code elimination by Java Compiler is what you are talking - this is very interesting question and I have to switch to Windows to run gcc and check the machine code for this Java program

Comment: @user1428716 i talking something like that, please try to help me, tnx

Answer (score 5):

What about this situation?

```
public class Foo
{
    private final int x;

    public Foo(int x){this.x = x;}

    public void boo()
    {
        switch(x)
        {
            case 200: System.out.println("200");
            case 300: System.out.println("300");
        }
    }
}
```

or maybe this one:

```
public static void doSomething(final int x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case 200: System.out.println("200");
        case 300: System.out.println("300");
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of posting the exact same answer, but u did it quick... +1

Answer (score 3):

```
switch(x){
    case 200: System.out.println("200"); break;
    case 300: System.out.println("300");
}
```

essentially means

```
if (x == 200)
  System.out.println("200");
else if (x == 300)
  System.out.println("300");
```

**It's just comparing, not assigning**, so the fact that `x` can't be modified doesn't matter.

Technically you example will be a little different (because you don't have a `break`):

```
if (x == 200)
  System.out.println("200");
if (x == 200 || x == 300)
  System.out.println("300");
```

or something like that.

The fact that `x` can never be `200` or `300` doesn't make the code not compile. It may however allow Java to optimise the switch statement away.

Comment: +1 for adding "The fact that x can never be 200 or 300 doesn't make the code not compile. It may however allow Java to optimise the switch statement away." I think this answers OP's question sufficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can pass a `final` parameter in a function:

```
//the function doesn't know what x  value is,
//but it knows that it can't modify its value
public someFunction(final int x) {

    x += 1; //compiler error
    switch(x) {
        case 200: System.out.println("200");
            break;
        case 300: System.out.println("300");
            break;
    }
}

//the function doesn't know what x value is,
//but it knows that it can modify it
//for internal usage
public someOtherFunction(int x) {

    switch(x) {
        case 200:
            x += 200;
            break;
        case 300:
            x += 300;
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: I think you are answering the same which OP is asking :)

Comment: gekkostate's comment is a best answer for this question.

Comment: @PradeepSimha answer updated. I guess now it addresses OP question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you got the point but how can i tell this to others? please help me,,,

Comment: did you really understant my question? please help meto tell it to others

Comment: @user2060289 I guess your question is *Why the `switch` statement can accept a `final` variable as parameter if compiler already knows its value*, but as shown in my example, it's not always like that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i want to know why is that,

Comment: @user2060289 well, my code shows a sample on why it should accept it. Just copy/paste it in your code and call the `someFunction(200); someFunction(300);` to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect the `final` modifier to make a difference? Nothing needs to be assigned to the value that's being switched on.

Are you sure you understand what the `switch` statement does?

Comment: yes i'm sure but the problem is why the it compiles even the case is a final variable,

Answer (score 1):

I think an optimization to remove or warn about `switch`-statements that are known at compile time to have be evaluated always to the same case is simply not implemented in the compiler, because that is a rare case.

The following code also compiles without warnings or errors.

```
  switch(3){
    case 2: 
      System.out.println("two"); 
      break;
    case 3: 
      System.out.println("three"); 
      break;
  }
```

A warning by the compiler about the unreachable code in the `case 2:` part would be nice, but is not implemented.

Comment: unlike this case in my code, the final variable is declared and used as an parameter in the switch statement, so the compiler knows that any oter value cannot be assigned to variable x an takes it as an constatnt 100, i'm asking' why a case statement can compile even the compiler knows that there cannot be cases in a final variable ,,,

Comment: @DJ Tishan: Why should the compiler not compile your code, even if none of the code in your switch block will ever be executed. Its syntax correct and therefore it is valid code. Your final variable is like my constant value both, yours and mine, lead to unreachable code, in both cases the compiler does not warn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most compiler optimize code using optimization algorithm which are rely on heuristics(experience-based techniques) and approximations. The below code would come into control flow analysis.
I ran a lot of samples of the program

Case A) if-else with final variable - Compiler throws a warning Dead Code. The generated byte code does not have any if-else statement.

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[])

Stack=1, Locals=2, Args_size=1
0:  iconst_0
1:  istore_1
2:  return
LineNumberTable: 
line 42: 0
line 54: 2

LocalVariableTable: 
Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
 0      3      0    args       [Ljava/lang/String;
 2      1      1    selection       I


 }
```

Case B) if-else without final variable - No compiler error but no code optimization too.

```
      final int selection i=100; //case A
      //int selection i=100; //case B

     if(selection==1){
         System.out.println("Hi");
  }else if(selection==2){

  }else{

   }
```

Case C) if-else with final variable but if-else statement is put in another method say

```
       computeIfLese(int selection)
```

- No code OPtimization done since this method can be invoked by other instance with different value of parameter ( Obviously).

Since the compiler optimization technique is based on heuristics , there would have been this case as a miss but who would think of the rarest of rarest case.

Comments from the Java Gods awaited... :)

Here is a living proof that Compiler has not optimized this.Check label 5:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
 Stack=2, Locals=2, Args_size=1
0:  bipush  100
2:  istore_1
3:  bipush  100
5:  lookupswitch{ //2
    200: 32;
    300: 40;
    default: 48 }
32: getstatic   #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
35: ldc #22; //String 200
37: invokevirtual   #24; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
40: getstatic   #16; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
43: ldc #30; //String 300
45: invokevirtual   #24; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
48: return
  LineNumberTable: 
line 11: 0
line 15: 3
line 17: 32
line 18: 40
line 21: 48

LocalVariableTable: 
Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
0      49      0    args       [Ljava/lang/String;
3      46      1    selection       I

StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 3
 frame_type = 252 /* append */
 offset_delta = 32
 locals = [ int ]
  frame_type = 7 /* same */
 frame_type = 7 /* same */


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside of having final parameters, a final local variable can hold values which are not known at compile-time:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    final int x;

    if (someMethod())
      x = 200;
    else
      x = 300;

    switch(x){
        case 200: System.out.println("200");
        case 300: System.out.println("300");
    }

}
```